# How to parse http multipart form data in c++/ how to find a delim in a binary data buffer

Tags: c++, http, parsing, multipartform-data

I am trying to write a program that will take a http message and chop it up into a vector of vector std::byte to hold http file transfers.

Here is an example of what a message will look like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------974767299852498929531610575

-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

some text
-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

(content of the uploaded file foo.txt)
-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575--
```

There is a text delim which seperates a blob of binary data. Using c++, how would you first find the delim in a large buffer of binary data.

Comment: I'd use libcurl or something instead of trying to deal with modern http manually.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search